# Overloading a Windows SQL server

Tags: sql-server, performance

We've been looking at a SQL based legacy system for the past few months trying to improve performance and have done as much as possible with the code base so now we're turning our attention to the infrastructure.

The problem is our legacy system encounters SQL timeouts, occasionally.

This legacy system is on the same server that runs all the SQL databases for the company. There are things like Sharepoint, Blackberry services, Server Virtualisation database for x9 virtual servers, numerous client-specific reporting databases that run on one SQL database on a mid-range server. The server's three years old. Can you give me an idea if this server is likely to be overloaded by these business services, and if so which one is most likely to be responsible? The company has, say 100-150 employees. Server has 4gb ram.

Additionally;

LegacySystemDB size:    14040384

SharepointSite1 size:   6581568

vCenter 3412928

SharepointSite2 size:   903032

Other db's approximately 50-100,000

Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL?

Comment: What does PerfMon tell you?

Comment: SQL 2005. What would PerfMon tell me? Never used it. Ok I'll do that, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer here is easy, buy more RAM and install it in the server.  With only 4 Gigs of RAM, SQL can probably only use 2 Gigs with the other 2 Gigs being used by Windows.  That only gives SQL about 1 Gig of memory for it to buffer data in.  Once that buffer is full any other data that SQL needs has to come from the disks.  My guess is that you are pulling data from the disk, leaving it in memory for just a few seconds and then flushing it out to make room for new data to go into memory.

Start by adding in more RAM.  Go for 16 Gigs total (12 more) and see how that helps performance.

Then have someone do some performance tuning on the indexes and see if there are any indexes which need to be added or removed.  Have you used SQL Profiler to identify the expensive queries and tune them?

Comment: More RAM - only if his architecture and edition of Windows server support it.

Comment: Also - don't suggest RAM as the first thing. You're just guessing; the OP should do some performance analysis of his system. Maybe hes' got a slow disk that holds tempdb and it's getting hammered. Maybe there are other problems in his IO setup that he hasn't described or even known to look for. Suggesting "more RAM" is not guaranteed to be the best first approach; it could be a waste of money.

Comment: Agreed. While it looks like RAM is an easy culprit here (4GB is very low) looking for things like Buffer I/O problems would be an easy way to see if you even need to get more RAM.

Comment: Espeically that very likely the server has no proer disc subsystem.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't just suggest more RAM, but with only 4 Gigs (that means pretty much no more than 2 for SQL) you can't really tell if the disks are able to keep up with the load until the database can cache enough info in RAM.  This is especially true when dealing with the vCenter database as it reads and writes lots of information through out the day.  I'm betting that if the OP were to look at the buffer cache data well find that it's not keeping data in cache more than a few seconds. Until the system has enough cache address disks will be very expensive.  RAM is cheap.

Comment: Hey @mfinni, perhaps you should check my bio. I do know a thing or two about SQL Server.  You can't properly diagnose a disk IO problem until you know why the SQL Server is thrashing the disk.  If the SQL Server can't keep the data in memory then its reading the same page from disk over and over putting a useless load on the disk.  Could more digging into the system be done, absolutely.  12 Gigs of RAM should cost a couple hundred bucks.  That will probably be a more cost effective diagnostic tool than spending hours digging into the system.

Comment: @Mrdenny - if it's not 64-bit Windows, or not better than Standard edition, more than 4 GB will do either nothing, or very little. If all his RAM banks are filled at 4 GB, getting 16 GB in there is going to be a little more expensive.

Comment: We now know (via the comments the OP left) that it's SQL 2005 which supports plenty of memory even with the 32bit standard edition.  The goal of adding more RAM is to increase the size of the buffer pool which can be increase on 32bit or 64bit systems with no problem.

Comment: +1 for sticking to your guns MrDenny! I'm with you one this one.  User3.. May find some comfort in looking at Page Life Expectancy alongside buffer cache hit ratio.